# self-signed certificate configuration in Selenium Standalone and webdriverio

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

How does one set in the configuration to accept insecure self-signed certificates.

I'm using Selenium Standalone and webdriverio.

https://github.com/vvo/selenium-standalone
https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio

I cannot read anywhere how to do this.

I'm suing the code below:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const exec = promisify(require('child_process').exec);

const selenium = require('selenium-standalone');
const webdriverio = require('webdriverio');

selenium.installAsync = promisify(selenium.install);
selenium.startAsync = promisify(selenium.start);

let browser;
let seleniumChild;

before(async function () {
    this.timeout(10 * 1000);

    try {
        // Remove any previous hanging sessions
        await exec('pkill -f selenium-standalone');
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.cmd !== 'pkill -f selenium-standalone') {
            console.error(error);
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }

    await selenium.installAsync({});
    seleniumChild = await selenium.startAsync({});

    const options = {
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome',
        },
        port: 4444,
    };

    browser = webdriverio.remote(options);
    await browser.init();
    await browser.url('http://google.com');
    const title = await browser.getTitle();
    console.log('Title ->', title);
    await browser.end();
});

describe('test', function () {
    it('test', async function () {
        assert.ok(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's starting a Selenium server, I'm expecting to be able to specify this through capabilities:

Did you tried using:

```
"acceptSslCerts": "true"
```

More on this topic you can find on the Selenium [github page](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities).